# Hide invisible unicode character

Tags: vim, unicode

I don't know why but vim shows invisible unicode characters with space. Just enter this in vim and you'll see.

`:tabe`

`:call setline(1, "\u2063hello")`

There is a space after "hello". How can I hide this space? Or is there a way how I can mark text in vim with something invisible? For instance, there is a text in file
`foo foo` and I want to highlight first "foo". At this moment I mark first "foo" with "\u2063" character `\u2063foo foo`.

Comment: Why do you expect that character to not be displayed?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2063/index.htm
I thought if there is an "invisible" in the title so it is invisible) So unicode has not really invisible character?

Comment: This char is invisible, but takes some space as any other char, it's quite the same as the space char.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but why is this character placed at the end of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

⁣hello
What you see depends on the terminal you're running Vim in. In GVIM (where Vim itself does the rendering), there indeed is an empty display cell at the beginning of the line. As Vim uses fixed, cell-based character addressing, this is expected. The U+2063 character is an invisible separator, but it still takes up one display cell.

Now, the terminal (I'm using Gnome Terminal) renders this character in a different way: It doesn't output anything. So Vim assumes the first cell has been occupied, and the `h`' of `hello` will be output at the second cell, but the terminal keeps the drawing cursor at the first cell, and all subsequent characters are rendered wrong. You can see the mismatch by moving around and using the `ga` command inside Vim.

Similar effects can be experienced with some combining characters, and other "funny" Unicode characters. I'm not sure whether the problem is with the terminal, Vim, or a mismatch in the interpretation of the terminal database.